# How to sort insert and prioritize most recent in an Array List?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I tried checking the array to see if the number is already listed, if the user happens to input a number twice thus number should be placed to the top being its most recent and everything else should be shifted down. in Short given the array [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 9] if the users inputs 7 it should be changed to [7, 4, 5, 6, 9].

```
//Array Created
int intArray[] = new int[5]; 

//Number of values in the array
int count = 0;

//Value user enters
int userInput = 0;

//Receive user inputs
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//First Prompt 
System.out.println("Enter The File You Wish To Use. Enter 0 to stop:");
userInput = in.nextInt();

//Keep asking for number if invalid
while((userInput < 0) || (userInput > 10)){
  System.out.println("Invalid number. Must be between 1 - 10\n");
  System.out.println("Enter The File You Wish To Use. Enter 0 to stop:");
  userInput = in.nextInt();
}

intArray[count] = userInput;
count++;


 while(userInput != 0){

   //Keeps Track of the numbers inputed 
  System.out.println("There is currently " + count + " On The Table.");
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
  }

  System.out.print("\n\n");
  System.out.println("Enter The File You Wish To Use. Enter 0 to stop:");
  
  userInput = in.nextInt();
  
  //Don't Allow numbers bigger than 10 or less than 1
  while(userInput < 0 || userInput > 10){
    System.out.println("Invalid number.\n");
    System.out.println("Enter The File You Wish To Use. Enter 0 to stop:");
    userInput = in.nextInt();
  } 

  if(count == intArray.length){
    int tempPrev;
    for(int i = (intArray.length - 1); i > 0; i--){
      
      //Store the previous value
      tempPrev = intArray[i - 1];

      //Assign current index to what was in previous
      intArray[i] = tempPrev;
    }
    
    intArray[0] = userInput;
    count = intArray.length;
  } else {
    intArray[count] = userInput;
    count++;
  }
}
System.out.println("The end.");
```

}
}

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide a solution for arrays and I will presume that if a new item is specified by the user, it will get to the head of the array and pulling everything to the right, with the oldest falling out of the array:

```
int index = intArray.indexOf(input);
if (index < 0) {
    index = intArray.length; //we default to the last item that would disappear
for (int i = index; i > 0; i--) {
    intArray[i] = intArray[i - 1];
}
intArray[0] = input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the fact that you need to have uniqueness in your array, so you want a set.

The best (quick) implementation you can find using the standard libraries is `LinkedHashSet<Integer>`.

If we analyze its documentation for a second we can see that by default it preserves the insertion order, which is perfect for your case, however, we also notice that it ignores re-insertions if the element is present:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in
> which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that
> insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the
> set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked
> when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the
> invocation.)

To get around this problem, you can create a utility function that first attempts to remove the number you want to insert from the set, then reinserts it again, thus changing the insertion order.

E.g.

```
final var set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
```

...

```
static void addFirst(Set<Integer> set, int val) {
  set.remove(val);
  set.add(val);
}
```

At this point you can take its iterator and read the set values as you need it most.

Note:
Since this is only efficient if the reads are in the direction of the iterator or if they are few compared to the inserts, so, if you have to iterate often in reverse then you are better off using a `LinkedList<Integer>`
directly and doing the same little game as `remove()` and `add()`.

That's because, unfortunately although the set is doubly linked, the only way you can scroll through it in reverse is as follows:

```
final var list = new LinkedList<>(set); 
final var it = list.descendingIterator(); 
while(it.hasNext()) {
   int item = it.next();
   // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping to you existing scheme, here is one way this could be accomplished. Read the comments in code:

Runnable code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AddNewButDeleteDuplicate_Demo {
    
    // System related newline character sequence. Could be used anywhere.
    public static final String LS = System.lineSeparator(); 
    
    // Open a keyboard input stream. Could be used anywhere.
    public static final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    
    // Application Entry Point:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // App started this way to avoid the need for statics:
        new AddNewButDeleteDuplicate_Demo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // This code can create an int[] array of any size:
        
        int[] intArray; // Declare our int[] array 
        int count = 1;  // Counter used for 'number of entries' display:
        
        // Inform of upcoming prompt:
        System.out.println("Enter integer numbers (1 to 10) to add to Array" + LS 
                           + "or enter 's' at any time to stop.");

        /* List Interface of Integer to hold all integer values supplied 
           by User.This List is later converted to an int[] Array. List
           is used because it can grow dynamically whereas Arrays can not. 
           This then allows the User to enter as many elements as desired
           which the rules specify 10 elements max since we can only enter 
           values from 1 to 10.                     */
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // To hold the current value supplied by User:
        String inputValue = "";  
        
        // Repeatable User Entry Prompt with a Stop mechanism and entry Validation:
        while (inputValue.isEmpty()) {
            // Prompt:
            System.out.print("Entry #" + count + ": -> ");
            // Get User Entry:
            inputValue = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            // Is 'Stop' desired?
            if (inputValue.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                // Yes...Inform and exit `while` loop
                System.out.println("Done Creating Array!");
                break;  // Exit `while` loop.
            }
            /* Validate User Entry. If the entry IS NOT a string representation
               of a unsigned integer value from 1 to 10 then indicate as invalid
               and allow the User to try again.        */
            if (!inputValue.matches("\\d+") || Integer.parseInt(inputValue) < 1 || 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(inputValue) > 10) {
                System.out.println(">> Invalid Entry (" + inputValue + ")! Try again... <<" + LS);
                inputValue = "";    // Empty variable to ensure re-loop.
                continue;  // Jump to top of loop:
            }

            /* If we made it to this point, then the User supplied value is 
               valid. Convert the User supplied string numerical value to 
               int data type.               */
            int val = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
            
            /* For demo purposes, display the Current List before checking
               for duplicates:         */
            System.out.println("List Previous: -> " + intList);
            
            // Check for duplicate...
            /* If List is not empty and the int value of the User supplied
               number IS currently contained within the List then remove the
               duplicate value already contained within the List and insert 
               the new (same) value to the beginning of the List at index 0.  */
            if (!intList.isEmpty() && intList.contains(val)) {
                int idx = intList.indexOf(val);
                /* If the duplicate is already located at index 0 of the List 
                   then there is no point doing any modification to the List
                   since this is where we would place the new value anyways. */
                if (idx != 0) {
                    intList.remove(idx); 
                    intList.add(0, val);
                    // Inform of duplicate entry:
                    System.out.println(">> Duplicate Entry (" + inputValue + ")! "
                            + "Old value removed at index " + idx + " and New value inserted "
                                    + "into index 0. <<" + LS);
                }
            }
            // Otherwise, just add the int value to the List:
            else {
                intList.add(val);
            }
            
            /* For demo purposes, display the Current List after checking
               for duplicates:         */
            System.out.println("List Current:  -> " + intList);
            
            inputValue = ""; // Empty variable to ensure re-loop.
            count++;  // Increment User entry count:
        }
        
        // Convert the List to an int[] Array using Streams:
        intArray = intList.stream().mapToInt(d -> d).toArray();
        
        // Display int[] Array:
        System.out.println("The intArray[] Array: -> " + Arrays.toString(intArray));
    }
}
```